# Is this SW comic from a larger story?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, comics

I don't have any actual images of this comic, sorry.

This was a one-volume comic that was in the end of a Star Wars comic I read.  At the time, I thought it was a preview for a longer full-length book.

The comic is set on Hoth and is focused on Kes Dameron and Shara Bey.  They're traveling through the tunnels to make a path for the Rebellion, but Kes is more unsure if the Rebellion will succeed.  The tunnel collapses and they both think they're dead, because destroying the tunnels to find them will undo so much of their work.  But Luke saves them with his lightsaber, and Leia's there too.  The comic ends with Kes telling his wife "We're going to win this."

Is this part of a longer story, or was it a special issue one-shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are searching for [*Empire Ascendant* 1](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Empire_Ascendant_1). It's a one-shot released in December of 2019, comprised of several short stories, including "An Echo of Victory" by Charles Soule. In that story, Shara Bey and Kes Dameron built tunnels in Echo Base. That should match your description of the comic.

[image: Shara at Echo Base]

Comment: As much as I applaud you for identifying the story first, this answer doesn't actually address the question asked, which is "*Is this SW comic from a larger story?*"

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're referring to the short comic [An Echo of Victory](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/An_Echo_of_Victory), originally published in [Empire Ascendant #1](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/76960/star_wars_empire_ascendant_2019_1). Kes Dameron and Shara Bey are cutting tunnels on Hoth in preparation for the Rebellion's arrival.

As you can see from the end piece, the story continues in [Star Wars #1 (2020)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(Marvel_2020)) with Keshara and Kes making appearances throughout the run.

[image]